# Python. Переменные не принимают значения из input

Tags: python, функции, переменные

```
login = (); password = (); login_login = (); pass_pass = ();
login_new = () ; password_new = (); question = ();

def loginning():
    login = input('Enter your login: ')
    password = input('Enter your password: ')
    if (login == 'user' and password == '12345'):
        print('Welcome back!')
    else:
        print('Incorrect login or password. Try again.')
        loginning()

def loginning_after_registration():
    login_login = input('Enter your login: ')
    pass_pass = input('Enter your pass: ')
    print('login_login =', login_login)
    print('pass_pass =', pass_pass)
    print('login_new =', login_new)
    print('password_new =', password_new)
    while ((login_login != 'user' and pass_pass != '12345') or 
(login_login != login_new and pass_pass != password_new)):
        print('Incorrect login or password. Try again.')
        loginning_after_registration()
    else:
        print('Welcome!')

def loginning_new():
    login_new = input('Think about your login: ')
    password_new = input('Think about your password: ')
    print('Thank you for registration!')
    print('Lets login in now.')
    loginning_after_registration()

def question_def():
    question = input('Do you already have an account (y/n)?: ')
    if (question == 'y' or question == 'Y'):
        print('Lets login in.')
        loginning()
    elif (question == 'n' or question == 'N'):
        print('Lets create your account!')
        loginning_new()
    else:
        print('Incorrect answer.')
        question_def()

question_def()
```

После ввода внутри `def loginning_new()` по идее переменные `login_new` и `password_new` должны принимать те значения, которые были указаны пользователем. Но после вывода переменных на экран, обе всегда равны неопределенному значению, а именно `"login_new = (); password_new = ()"`.

Более того, обе эти переменных в PyCharm подсвечиваются серым, а не белым. Как это исправить и как сделать, чтобы значения принимались. Покажите на примере, пожалуйста.

Comment: Покажите полную версию кода. Где вы переменные и как определили, где вы их выводите на экран и где вызываете функцию для переопределения значений

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Ваши функции не имеют входных обязательных параметров или необязательных параметров. Вся основная часть программы это объявление функций.
В конце вы запускаете одну функцию: question_def().  В рамках её выполнения все идет последовательно. И логично, что после запуска функции loginning_new().. в рамках её выполнения вызывается loginning_after_registration(). Соответственно, в рамках е1 выполнения и запрашивается заново:  print('login_new =', login_new)
    print('password_new =', password_new)

Answer (score 2):

Изменение глобальных переменных не доступно из функций.

Для возможности изменения глобальных переменных из функций, используется ключевое слово **global**. [Подробнее про global в документации](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/globalnye-peremennye-python)

Пример:

```
def loginning_after_registration():
    global login_login
    login_login = input('Enter your login: ')
    global pass_pass
    pass_pass = input('Enter your pass: ')
    print('login_login =', login_login)
    print('pass_pass =', pass_pass)
    global login_new
    global password_new
    print('login_new =', login_new)
    print('password_new =', password_new)
    while ((login_login != 'user' and pass_pass != '12345') or
        (login_login != login_new and pass_pass != password_new)):
        print('Incorrect login or password. Try again.')
        loginning_after_registration()
    else:
        print('Welcome!')


def loginning_new():
    global login_new
    login_new = input('Think about your login: ')
    global password_new
    password_new = input('Think about your password: ')
    print('Thank you for registration!', login_new)
    print('Lets login in now.', password_new)
    loginning_after_registration()


def question_def():
    question = input('Do you already have an account (y/n)?: ')
    if question == 'y' or question == 'Y':
        print('Lets login in.')
        loginning()
    elif question == 'n' or question == 'N':
        print('Lets create your account!')
        loginning_new()
    else:
        print('Incorrect answer.')
        question_def()

question_def()
```

Answer (score 0):

использовать global это плохая привычка лучше научится использовать [return](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.16.php)

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите, как это сделать. Иначе ваш ответ — хотя вы в нем прав — не является ответом, а комментарием к другому ответу, и может быть удален.